# Differences between IE and chrome for iframes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, iframe, edit

I know there must be tons of post on IE vs Chrome and stuff, but I can't find what I'm looking for.

I'm developing a website and it seems that some content won't do the same thing on each browser... I know that it some cases we need do special code for IE, but in my case, it only works on IE and won't work on Chrome... which I find it kinda weird.

In my case, I'm trying to insert an `<iframe>` in my page that will show text, images and stuff (like word... for exemple) and I have some javascript to enable me from editing the content of the `<iframe>`

```
function init() {
    iView.document.designMode = 'On';
    if (is_ie) docobj = document.frames['myView'].document;
    if (is_ie) AttachEventListener(docobj,"keydown",new Function("HtmlEditProcessKeyPressed('myView')"));
}
```

And here's the frame

```
<iframe id="myView" style="width: 850px; height: 325px" width="940" height="250" src="<%=PATH%>/document"></iframe>
```

That works perfectly fine on IE ; I can see the text from my document and I can edit it without problem.

However, in chrome (haven't tried any other browser), the background color of the frame is gray and I can't edit the text... but I can see it.

Any explication / theory is appreciated, thanks

Comment: `designMode` is IE-only.  You want `contentEditable`.

Comment: `AttachEventListener` doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes I tried with `contentEditable` but it doesn't work either on Chrome

Comment: Finally I changed all the editor for CKEditor.